# In lodash, what is the opposite of `pairs()`?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I cant't see it in the docs - http://lodash.com/docs - please help me:

What is the opposite of `_.pairs()`? There must be one - I just cant' see where!

The goal is to produce key/value pairs from an array of the form `[['key1':'value1'], ['key2':'value2'], ...]`

Not that I really need it a lib for that: I just like to re-use things..

Comment: http://lodash.com/docs#zipObject

Comment: if it's key,value pairs, I think http://lodash.com/docs#reduceRight may prove more helpfull

Comment: I wish the `_.zipObject` documentation examples showed both usage forms. I saw the two-array invocation example and assumed that was the only way to use it, since most other Lo-Dash documentation examples show multiple forms.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think you're looking for `_.object`/`_.zipObject`.

http://lodash.com/docs#zipObject

```
"use strict";

var obj, pairs, objResult;

obj = {
    key1: "value1",
    key2: "value2"
};

pairs = _.pairs(obj);
objResult = _.object(pairs);

// The original object.
console.log(obj);
// The object as an array of arrays.
console.log(pairs);
// The array of arrays converted back to the original object.
console.log(objResult);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HmDk6/

Comment: See answer below since version 4.

Answer (score 9):

Since version 4, `_.fromPairs`

> The inverse of `_.toPairs`; this method returns an object composed from
>   key-value pairs.

https://lodash.com/docs#fromPairs

Comment: thanx @ricardo-stuven!